# Postgres readonly user cannot access tables

Tags: postgresql

I need help creating two Postgres users, one that is readonly and another that is read-write including creating new tables that the readonly user can select.

Here are the commands I'm using, as the admin user, that fulfills the requirement for the read-write user but not the readonly user.  The problem is new tables created by the read-write user cannot be read by the readonly user.  What am I doing wrong?

```
  > create database portal;
  > \c portal
  > revoke create on schema public from public;
  > revoke all on database portal from public;

  > create role portal_reader noinherit;
  > grant connect on database portal to portal_reader;
  > grant usage on schema public to portal_reader;
  > grant select on all tables in schema public to portal_reader;
  > alter default privileges in schema public grant select on tables to portal_reader;
  > grant portal_reader to portal_ro;

  > create role portal_writer noinherit;
  > grant connect on database portal to portal_writer;
  > grant all on schema public to portal_writer;
  > grant all on all tables in schema public to portal_writer;
  > alter default privileges in schema public grant all on tables to portal_writer;
  > grant all on all sequences in schema public to portal_writer;
  > alter default privileges in schema public grant all on sequences to portal_writer;
  > grant portal_writer to portal;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES lack a FOR USER clause, so they apply only to objects created by the user you were logged in as the time they were executed.  We don't know who that was, but clearly it isn't "portal_writer".

Comment: That's good to know about the "for role <target_role>".  Unfortunately adding it still doesn't solve my problem of providing read access to the portal_reader role i.e. this doesn't help when run by the admin user or the portal user: alter default privileges for role portal_writer in schema public grant select on tables to portal_reader;

Comment: @Jay works for me.  But you have 4 roles you are using here (5 if you count the script runner), and 2 of them were never created in your example, plus you never create any table, so I don't know what you are actually doing.