# postgres -- default privilidges are not set when initializing db in docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, privileges

This is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66035751/postgres-readonly-user-cannot-access-tables) question as the one 1) does not seem to have an accepted answer and 2) the proposed answer neither alleviates my problem (as I implemented the advise contained there but the problem remained) nor seem to have helped the OP of the mentioned question anyways.

I am trying to run a postgres docker container. Before container startup the initialization script is run with the sole purpose of creating a db and a couple of users with predefined privileges -- in this example `admin` ought to have all the necessary privileges and `reader`, well, is bound to only `SELECT` stuff. The tables inside the db are created by `admin` from other container.

All's good, but **the problem is** that `reader` can not only `SELECT` but do other stuff like `INSERT`.

In the below init script written (presumably) according to [the docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres#Initialization_scripts) I initially tried to create users without intermingling roles -- but that blocker any access for `reader` at all. Then I tried to put the `reader` in the role of `admin` and limit unnecessary privileges, but the latter didn't go. The latest revision of the script I show below.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "$POSTGRES_DB" <<-EOSQL
    CREATE DATABASE db;
    REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE db FROM PUBLIC;

    CREATE USER admin;
    ALTER USER admin PASSWORD '$ADMIN_PASS';
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE db TO admin;
    ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES 
        GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLES TO admin;

    CREATE USER reader IN ROLE admin;
    ALTER USER reader PASSWORD '$READER_PASS';
    REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE db FROM reader;
    ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES 
        REVOKE ALL ON TABLES FROM reader;
    GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE db TO reader;
    ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES 
        GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO reader;
EOSQL
```

**EDIT:**
The last edition of the script is the following, accounting for comments below, but the problem persist.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "$POSTGRES_DB" <<-EOSQL
    CREATE DATABASE db;

    CREATE USER admin;
    ALTER USER admin PASSWORD '$ADMIN_PASS';

    CREATE USER reader IN ROLE admin;
    ALTER USER reader PASSWORD '$READER_PASS';
EOSQL

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname db <<-EOSQL
    REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE db FROM PUBLIC;

    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE db TO admin;
    ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES 
        FOR ROLE admin
        GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLES TO admin;

    REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE db FROM reader;
    ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES 
        FOR ROLE admin
        REVOKE ALL ON TABLES FROM reader;
    GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE db TO reader;
    ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES 
        FOR ROLE admin
        GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO reader;
EOSQL
```

Comment: The old mistake: you have to use `FOR ROLE admin` in `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, hey, thank you for stopping by for a comment! I added `FOR ROLE` statement into all (three) of `ALTER DEFAULT` ones, but it doesn't seem to fix anything. May you specify if it should be inserted only into some of them?

Comment: In addition, there is a second mistake that i see only now. Default privileges affect only the current database. So you have to connect to `db` before running the `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGE` settings.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, thank you one more time, but that does not seem to work. I tried moving everything  but first `CREATE` and `REVOKE` statements into new `psql` command (trying to connect as superuser again) -- `reader` still managed to `INSERT`. I then moved creation of `admin` and setting his database privileges (not tables) to the first `psql` command too, trying next to connect to the new db with this user and do the rest, but it failed with an `permission denied to create role` error.
Could you please point me into the direction to think, as I am unfortunately already off of ideas.

Comment: That last script will work. The `REVOKE` is unnecessary, but every table created by `admin` in database `db` will have to `SELECT` privilege for `reader`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe unfortunately the problem is not that `reader` does not have `SELECT` rights, but rather that all the rest are also present. Even with the last script from the edit to the question (including revocations of, well, `REVOKE` as you suggested) `reader` is still able to `INSERT`.

Comment: Well, `reader` is a member of `admin`. That means, `reader` inherits all privileges from `admin`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe yes, I've put it there precisely because you wrote it in your very first comment. `reader` could've interacted with the created database from the very beginning as the questions says, the sole problem is to *limit* its' privileges. So could you point me into the right direction to think please, as other materials I found on this topic seem (for me) to only confirm that the last script (that is doing wrong thing) is doing all fine.

Comment: My comment said to use `FOR ROLE admin` in `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`, not `IN ROLE admin` in `CREATE ROLE reader`. The latter is your current problem.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe oh yeas, this one slipped into the script somewhere in the middle. Well, indeed the root of the problem that was! Thank you once again for your patience!

But now `FOR ROLE` starts to confuse me -- as I may understand it means that the privileges are altered for everything created (owned) by the role the statement is pointing at. But what about things created by other roles -- can I limit someone's permissions for *everything* in the db no matter who initially created it?

Comment: Yes, it is only for tables created by `admin`. You'd have to run an `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` for every role that can create tables.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe and there is no way to make it work with all the tables by default?

Comment: No, unless you want to write event triggers. Limit the number of roles that can create tables.